# Django view not passing array to template

Tags: django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django.
I've parsed an XML file and when it's printed, I see all the titles and links in the xml file printed in the terminal (about 15 entries).
However, then I try to display them in my template, it only returns a single entry (title and link). What am I doing wrong? Am not sure why arr and print are yielding different results.

**view.py**

```
def madxmlparser(request):
    url = 'https://www.example.com/rss/current.xml'
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(url))
    root = tree.getroot()

    for entry in root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
        title = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title').text
        link = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link').attrib['href']
        arr = [title, link]
        print(title, link)
    return render(request, 'madxmlparser.html', {'arr':arr})
```

**template.py**

```
{% for i in arr %}
  <div class="row">
    {{ i }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning arr to a new link and title every iteration of the loop. Instead you want to create an array that holds every title and link, so you have to append every iteration.
The problem you are facing is a python problem and not a django problem.

```py
def madxmlparser(request):
    url = 'https://www.example.com/rss/current.xml'
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(url))
    root = tree.getroot()

    arr = []  # initialize empty list

    for entry in root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
        title = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title').text
        link = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link').attrib['href']
        arr.append([title, link])  # append to that list
        # print(title, link)
    # print(arr)
    return render(request, 'madxmlparser.html', {'arr':arr})
```

`arr` then is a "bigger" list, containing "smaller" lists. The "smaller" lists each contain a `title` and a `link`. So `arr` is a list of pairs of `title` and `link`. 
`arr = [ [title1, link1], [title2, link2], ... ]`

```html
{% for i in arr %}
  <div class="row">
    Title: {{ i.0 }} and Link: {{ i.1 }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This loop unfolds the list of pairs. The number behind the variable `i` is used to index the "smaller" lists. Another option would be the following:

```html
{% for title, link in arr %}
  <div class="row">
    Title: {{ title }} and Link: {{ link }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Tarquinius, the append solved the issue. I modified it a little more to make it cleaner.

arr.append(title + ' ' + link)

{% for i in arr %}
  <div class="row">
    {{ i }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

Comment: Say for example I wanted to loop through the title and links as pairs, and show them separately in the template, how would I do that?

I can store them like this:
`arr = {'title':title, 'link':link}`
And retrieve like this:
` {% for i in arr %}`
`   <div class="card">`
`      <small>Source</small> &#8729; <small> 1 hour ago</small>`
`       <h3>title{{ arr.title }}</h3>`
`       <p>link{{ arr.link }}</p>`
`   </div>`
`  {% endfor %}`
But still have the problem of not appending the new values.

Comment: Your modification is exactly what makes using the title independently from the link **im**possible. Your "modification" does not allow splitting because you create one string. Just do exactly what I showed and you can insert title and link wherever you want with using (as I showed) `{{ i.0 }}` for the title and `{{ i.1 }}` for the link.